# Increasing Pool size in JEDIS will affect redis performance?

Tags: redis, jedis

Consider a scenario my application needs only 100 jedisPool connections to fetch data from redis server. What happen if I configure 500 as max pool size keeping in mind that my application needs more connections in future. Does it affect the redis performance. If yes, what is the severity of this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default max clients for Redis is 10000, you can check it with `CONFIG GET maxclients`. So if you ever get to 500 connections is quite manageable. If you will have multiple Jedis clients then consider the product nodes*maxTotal. See https://redis.io/topics/clients

You can expect a soft performance decrease as your number of clients increases. You probably want to run some [benchmarks](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).

I tried `redis-benchmark -t set -r 100000 -n 1000000 -c 500` where `-c 500` is the number of clients. From 50 to 500 clients I got a 12% decrease in requests-per-second.

Check this out for [JedisPool optimization](https://partners-intl.aliyun.com/help/doc-detail/98726.htm#h2-url-3).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the max pool size is just a max limit. 
If you set it to 500, and your APP only needs 100, the pool will not actually create 500 connections int it. So i guess this will not affect performance issues to your case.
And there are other params to manage the connections:
        **config.setMaxIdle();
        config.setMaxTotal();**
you may make a test, and use cmd "info" to see the connections.